# Gridview not exporting last row in the excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I'm trying to export the contents of the gridview to excelsheet and the last row of the gridview is always missing in the excel sheet.

I think it might be due to the header row but could not figure out how to overcome this. Below is the code for exporting to excel sheet

```
private void btnExportToExcel_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            //To Export all pages
            GridView1.AllowPaging = false;

            GridView1.RenderControl(hw); //here gridview is not rendering last row 

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
```

Comment: You aren't creating an Excel file anyways. You're creating an HTML file and then serving it up with a Excel MIME type and file extension. Why not use a library capable of generating a real Excel file? EPPlus, NPOI, Closed XML, or Office XML SDK?

Comment: Even though I render it to HTML or external third pary tools like iTextSharp, Gridview1.RenderControl(hw) will skip the last row for some reason

Comment: And if you use one of the libraries I mentioned above to export the data source directly instead of going through the GridView, you won't have this issue.

Comment: My work requires to have minimal third party tools dependency. Since I'm able to export and get the excel file, may be some small code change might fix it and meet the requirement

Comment: That's ridiculous. You should go make your use case clear to them: you need to generate actual valid Excel files, not hacky junk. And re-inventing the wheel is dangerous and a waste of your time and the company's time. Anyways, Office XML SDK is provided by Microsoft, perhaps they won't consider that to be 3rd party.

Comment: Yes agree, thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine for me. Here is my code behind with simple data.My aspx page has just a grid and an export button

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("Id");
    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Id"] = 1;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["Id"] = 2;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    //To Export all pages
    grdTest.AllowPaging = false;
    grdTest.AllowSorting = false;
    grdTest.DataSource = dt;
    grdTest.DataBind();
}
public override void VerifyRenderingInServerForm(Control control)
{
    /* Verifies that the control is rendered */
}

protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    {
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=GridViewExport.xls");
        Response.Charset = "";
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        {
            HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

            grdTest.RenderControl(hw); //here gridview is not rendering last row 

            //style to format numbers to string
            string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
            Response.Write(style);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I could not found solution online anywhere but I found the reason why this was happening, it was due to one additonal GridviewRow being added to the gridview on rowDatabound, and that addition of single row was skipping the very last row.

To fix this, before gridview databinding, I added one empty footer row to workaround the issue:

```
        DataRow dr= dt.NewRow();
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
```